# iOS Combining images to Parse.com

Tags: ios, image, blend

I want to combine two images and send them as one to a Parse database. 
Only I get no image as result.

This is my code:
.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>


@interface mailViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *naamText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dankView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonLogo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *mailImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *achtergrondImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *coverImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *achtergrond;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *finalImage;

 - (IBAction)send:(id)sender;
 - (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

 @end
```

.m file

```
  #import "mailViewController.h"
  #import "cat01ViewController.h"

@interface mailViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *finalImage;

@end

@implementation mailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    self.naamText.delegate = self;
    self.emailText.delegate = self;

    self.mailImage.image = self.coverImage;


    //hide dankwoord
    self.dankView.hidden = YES;
    _label.hidden = YES;
    _buttonLogo.hidden = YES;


    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
      if (self.coverImage != nil)
        self.mailImage.image = self.coverImage;
}

- (void)addImages{

    UIImage *image1 = self.mailImage.image;
    UIImage *image2 = self.achtergrond;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width, image1.size.height + image2.size.height);

    [image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, image1.size.height)];
    [image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,image1.size.height,size.width, image2.size.height)];

    self.finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Add image to view
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,               self.finalImage.size.width, self.finalImage.size.height)];
    imageView.image = self.finalImage;
    [self.view addSubview: imageView];

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [self.naamText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.emailText resignFirstResponder];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

   if (textField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    PFObject *emailadres = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"emailadres"];
    [emailadres setObject:_naamText.text forKey:@"name"];
    [emailadres setObject:_emailText.text forKey:@"email"];
    emailadres[@"iPad_nr"] = @"iPad 2";
    [emailadres saveInBackground];

    self.dankView.hidden = NO;
    _label.hidden = NO;
    _buttonLogo.hidden = NO;


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC),   dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       _label.hidden = YES;
    });

    return NO;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {

    [self.naamText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.emailText resignFirstResponder];

    UIImage *image = self.finalImage;

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.png" data:imageData];

    PFObject *mailPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"mailPhoto"];
    mailPhoto[@"imageName"] = @"Ikzieikzie";
    mailPhoto[@"imageFile"] = imageFile;
    [mailPhoto setObject:_naamText.text forKey:@"name"];
    [mailPhoto setObject:_emailText.text forKey:@"email"];
    mailPhoto[@"iPad_nr"] = @"iPad 1";
    [mailPhoto saveInBackground];

    self.dankView.hidden = NO;
    _label.hidden = NO;
    _buttonLogo.hidden = NO;


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _label.hidden = YES;
    });

}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {

    [self.naamText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.emailText resignFirstResponder];

    self.dankView.hidden = NO;
    _label.hidden = NO;
    _buttonLogo.hidden = NO;


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _label.hidden = YES;
    });

}

@end
```

So, I know how to send the images individual to the Parse database... but I cant understand how to combine them and send them as one.

Comment: You never set self.finalImage (as in a class instance variable) to contain the combined image.

Answer (score 0):

You set the local variable `finalImage` in `addImages`, you never set a class variable `self.finalImage` to contain the combined image, so this line

```
UIImage *image = self.finalImage;
```

probably sets `image` to nil.

Also, you never add the `UIImageView *imageView` in `addImages` as a subview as you've probably intended.

So to fix this code, I'd recommend creating defining `finalImage` as a class property at the top of the class, ex:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *finalImage;

@end
```

Then in `addImages` you can change the local variable `finalImage` to `self.finalImage` and properly add the `UIImageView` as a subview, ex:

```
self.finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Add image to view
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.finalImage.size.width, self.finalImage.size.height)];
imageView.image = self.finalImage;
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

After making these changes you can still use this line in `send:`:

```
UIImage *image = self.finalImage;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesnt work. What di is use to send to parse? 
UIImage *image = self.finalImage; is not ok, so? instead self.finalImage only finalImage?

Comment: No, update the code like I've said then still use `UIImage *image = self.finalImage;` in `send:`.

Comment: I get an error in this line;
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, finalImage.size.width, finalImage.size.height)];

It wants to change it in ... _finalImage.size.. etc

Comment: Yeah, because we were supposed to change all `finalImage` mentions to `self.finalImage`, but I forgot to make the change there too.

Comment: Yes, tried it... Still no image. It sends an image to parse, but it is still empty.

Comment: @Melissa Is your imageView subview also empty?

Comment: @Melissa OK, so the problem's not with uploading to Parse... And I don't see any issues with the drawing of your context, but are you 100% sure, `self.mailImage.image` and `self.achtergrond` contain images?

Comment: Hi, i edited and put on all the code... Maybe you can see what's wrong. Maybe its the hierarchy? I am not that familiar with coding yet, this is my first app.

Comment: First observation: From your code, self.achtergrond looks like it hasn't been set and probably equals nil. Also self.coverImage looks like it equals nil and since that's what you're using to set self.mailImage.image in viewDidLoad, I'm confused as to how an image is showing up for you...

Comment: @Melissa What happens if you try to NSLog image1 and image2 in `addImages`? What does it say?

Comment: You are right! self.achtergrond is nil, my mistake. It should have been self.achtergrondImage.image. 
self.mailImage.image is a drawing a user makes in another viewcontroller, so it's send to coverImage to display.
When i tried NSLog it didn't return anything... So, i searched again and finally found a solution! see new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the context, it should be focused to imageview object not to the image object.
Try this:

```
UIImage *image1 = self.mailImage.image;
UIImage *image2 = self.achtergrond;

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width, image1.size.height + image2.size.height);

[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, image1.size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,image1.size.height,size.width, image2.size.height)];

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

//Add image to view
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, finalImage.size.width, finalImage.size.height)];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

imageView.image = finalImage;

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives an error here;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGRectMake(0, 0, finalImage.size.width, finalImage.size.height)); 
'passing CGRect (aka struct)..'

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the final solution! Thanks for your help!

```
UIImage *image1 = self.achtergrondImage.image;
UIImage *image2 = self.mailImage.image;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image1.size);
[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image1.size.width, image1.size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(image1.size.width - image2.size.width, image1.size.height - image2.size.height, image2.size.width, image2.size.height)];

self.finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.finalImage.size.width, self.finalImage.size.height)];
imageView.image = self.finalImage;
```